# Como eliminar uma chave estrangeira o MySql

Tags: mysql

Estou a ter o mesmo problema em todos bancos de dados.
Tenho um banco de dados criado com as seguintes linhas

```
create database nova;
create table estado(
        id int primary key auto_increment, 
        nome varchar(20)
        );
create table pessoa(
        id int primary key auto_increment, 
        nome varchar(20), 
        estado int, 
        foreign key (estado) references estado(id)
        );
```

E pretendo eliminar o campo estado na tabela pessoa, obtive os seguintes erros ao executar as seguintes linhas:

```
alter table pessoa drop estado
```

## 1553 - Cannot drop index 'estadoAtuall': needed in a foreign key constraint

```
ALTER TABLE pessoa DROP INDEX estado;
ALTER TABLE pessoa DROP COLUMN estado
```

## 1553 - Cannot drop index 'estado': needed in a foreign key constraint

```
set FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;
alter table pessoa drop estado
```

## 1828 - Cannot drop column 'estado': needed in a foreign key constraint 'nova/pessoa_ibfk_1'

Answer (score 4):

Você poderia remover primeiro a foreign key com a seguinte sintaxe:

```
ALTER TABLE pessoa DROP FOREIGN KEY NOME_FOREIGN_KEY;
```

Caso seja necessário remover índices:

```
ALTER TABLE pessoa DROP INDEX NOME_INDEX;
```

Em seguida, você pode seguir com a remoção da coluna:

```
ALTER TABLE pessoa DROP COLUMN estado;
```

Para você verificar o nome da foreign key e índices gerados, execute o seguinte comando:

```
show create table pessoa;
```

Comment: Foi algo que eu esqueci de mencionar, mas quando eu executo esta linha:alter table pessoa drop FOREIGN key estado
Dá o seguinte erro: 
#1091 - Can't DROP 'estado'; check that column/key exists
Mas a coluna existe

Comment: Qual o retorno quando você executa o comando: SHOW CREATE TABLE PESSOA?

Answer (score 2):

Caso alguém ainda procure por isso eu consegui dessa forma:

```
show create table pessoa;
```

você deve encontrar algo como

> CONSTRAINT `pessoa_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`estado`)
> REFERENCES `estado` (`id`)

Use o comando `ALTER TABLE pessoa DROP CONSTRAINT pessoa_ibfk_1` para remover a constraint da coluna estado.

Use `ALTER TABLE pessoa DROP INDEX estado;` para remover a chave estrangeira da coluna estado.

Após esses dois comandos você poderá remover a coluna.

Answer (score 0):

Eu também tinha o mesmo problema com a minha base de dados.

Pesquisei e a solução que encontrei foi essa:

```
show create table tabela;
```

> Obs. Substitua a palavra tabela pelo nome da tua tabela.

Depois vai aparecer algo semelhante a isto:

```
CONSTRAINT 'tabela_ibfk_2' FOREIGN KEY (nome_da_chave) REFERENCES 'tabela'(id_tabela)
```

Feito isso, escreva o seguinte comando:

```
alter table 'tabela' drop foreign key tabela_ibfk_2;
```

Em seguida, execute a seguinte instrução:

```
alter table 'tabela' drop 'nome_da_chave';
```

> Lembrando mais uma vez que tens de substituir os nomes apresentados
> aqui pelos respetivos nomes da tua tabela.